Web Apps behind Application Gateway are not able to validate authentication, resulting in 500 Internal server error from AG
I have a several App Services which are Linux webapps, named my-app1, my-app2.
First I configured Authentication for the apps using a porvider I have. I followed the instructions here
I tested that authentication works using my-app1.azurewebsites.net and my-app2.azurewebsites.net URLs.
I don't want the apps to be available via azurewebsites.net, but instead to have them both behind an Application Gateway with one URL. So I have a URL for the gateway at my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com and I configured path-based routes for the both off the apps:

my-app1 -> /*
my-app2 -> /tools/*

I turned the authentication off in the apps, and tested that the apps are available. Until here all  is good.
But here the problems begin. When I turned the authentication on I started seeing "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" error from my IDP provider.
The problem was that the redirect_uri parameter was filled with my-app1.azurewebsites.net instead of my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com (and my-app2.azurewebsites.net instead of my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/tools)
To overcome this issue I followed the instructions here. It solved the authentication problem, I'm one step closer to solution, but here is the main issue.
Behind the gateway I get 500 Internal Server Error response from the gateway.
I followed the requests, this is the flow:

request to my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
redirect to  my IDP provider - here I have a response header with "Set-Cookie" that has the needed JWT.
redirect back to my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com where I receive 500 Internal Server Error

When I inspect the a flow without Application Gateway, in 3. I receive a Cookie called AppServiceAuthSession and then everything is good.
I assume that AppServiceAuthSession was created by Azure middleware that is responsible for managing the authentication after they validated the JWT that was provided by my IDP provider, but for some reason the process is not able to complete if Application Gateway is involved. It's also important to note that when this 500 error happens I don't see any logs in the app so this is why I suspect the issue to be in the middleware-gateway area.
My only lead now is this post here where the person mentioned that some headers were missing but unfortunately didn't elaborate which.
Edit: There is a small hint on the post of setting authentication behind Azure Front door here about setting forward_proxy_convention = "Standard". I tried it but so far without any luck. They also leave a vague comment of:

Other reverse proxies like Azure Application Gateway or 3rd-party products might use different headers and need a different forwardProxy setting.

Edit2: I did as documented here, for Application Gateway you need to setup:
forward_proxy_convention              = "Custom"
forward_proxy_custom_host_header_name = "X-Original-Host"

It worked. The main site is now able to authenticate fully. But for the "/tools/*" app the authentication is failing to be validated.
I also noticed that my original rewrite rules of ...azurewebsites.net -> ...cloudapp.azure.com is not needed any more, but a more complicate rewrite will be needed:

if uri_path is /tools/
and location header has redirect_uri with my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
then rewrite location header to have under redirect_uri my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/tools

I found that there are logs from the EasyAuth middleware 400 (Bad Request). Partial response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Incorrect redirect_uri"} because to my understanding the middleware is not able to rebuild the callback url correctly.
Specifically, instead of my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/tools/.auth/... the middleware is probably only able to build my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/.auth/... which is of course not a correct validation URL.
I don't know how can I affect EasyAuth and force it to build the URL correctly. Any help on the topic will be much appreciated

This was indeed my first issue, but I solved it by rewriting the response_header. I search the Location header for my-app1.azurewebsites.net and replace it with my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com and I search for my-app2.azurewebsites.net and replace it with my-gw.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com%2Ftools. it has to be %2F and not / because the URI is encoded as the value of redirect_uri

To solve this issue I had to add more configuration to the app service.
This configuration cannot be done via Azure Portal, only in cli, in my case I did it via terraform.
Under the auth_settings_v2 block, those two needs to be added:
forward_proxy_convention              = "Custom"
forward_proxy_custom_host_header_name = "X-Original-Host"

This will fix the routing problems for setting the app behind an Application Gateway.
If anyone Azure Front Door users landed here, know that for you it should be enough to only set forward_proxy_convention = "Standard".
If anyone cares about more info, I found the solution in the "Alternative approaches" section of a post about setting up custom domains here
Edit: unfortunately this is only a partial solution.
The authentication works for the main app, the one that is available at / via the AG.
If the other apps (in my case /tools) is using the same authentication provider with the same parameters then I can authenticate with the main app, receive AppServiceAuthSession cookie and it will be used for the other apps.
But if the other apps use a different authentication provider than there will still be the 500 Internal server error.
